# Roots of $g(z) - g(e^{i \theta})$ in terms of $\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Given a complex polynomial

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^N c_n z^n $$

I'd like to express the roots of $f(z) = g(z) - g(e^{i \theta})$ as some function of $\theta$.

I've been experimenting with graphing the path of the roots as $\theta$ changes and the result looks like a smooth curve.  Moreover, the roots actually trace paths which sometimes meet up with the paths from other roots to form larger paths.  So it looks like the roots are evenly spaced points on one or more complex curves.

For instance, for $g(z) = .16z^3 + \frac{1}{2}z^2 + z$, the trace looks like (the black circle is the unit circle, for scale):

[image: trace of roots of a sample function]

So I'm guessing there's some nice form for the paths the roots trace and their positions on these paths, but I'm not sure how to begin approaching this problem.

Comment: Well, one root should be $z= \exp(\mathrm i t)$, but that does not show in your animation?

Comment: this problem is way too vague, but one thing I would check is a case where there is a critical point on the unit circle and also another case where there is a critical point outside the unit circle but the critical value is taken on the unit circle too and see the behavior in those cases because polynomials tend to change behavior precisely at critical points and values

Comment: @WimC You're absolutely right!  Turns out I was graphing the roots of $g(z) + g(e^{i \theta})$ instead of the difference.  I've updated the graph with the corrected version.

Comment: @Conrad I'm not sure what part of the question you find vague?  Maybe I can explain it better if you let me know which part is unclear.  Regarding the critical values, how do you define or find critical values when there's two independent variables?  I could find the critical values holding $\theta$ constant at some arbitrary value but I'm not sure how to do it for arbitrary values of $\theta$.  I imagine the critical values would move similarly to the roots, in curves.

Comment: I find it vague in the sense of what are your expectations when you say "I'd like to express..."; as noted by general theory one can show that polynomial roots are continuous in terms of the coefficients (with appropriate interpretations of multiplicity), but not sure if one can go beyond this to something concrete, etc ;what I meant is to find an example where $g'(1)=0$ say, and see what happens with the roots of $g-g(e^{i\theta})$ for $\theta$ close to zero; same to find a polynomial for which $g'(2)=0, g(1)=g(2), g'(1) \ne 0$ and see what happens

Comment: @Conrad I'm imagining something like calculating a root of $g(z) - g(0)$ first, then using a conformal map to warp the space such that that root becomes $e^{i \theta}$.  Then the root's path is just the unit circle.  The root path in unwarped space is the unit circle warped by the inverse of the conformal mapping.  I don't know if that procedure would actually work or not, but that's the sort of solution I was imagining.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a contribution to the overall problem, too big to fit into a comment. Maybe this can inspire a real proof by someone else.

I think it'll be pretty easy to show that the paths are continuous, so long as you can define the path in a way that accurately "traces" one of the roots around. To this end, let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a polynomial. Now fix $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ and let $c=f(z_0)$. I claim that for every real $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $c_1\in\mathbb{C}$, if $|c_1-c|<\delta$, then there exists $z_1\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z_1-z_0|<\epsilon$ such that $f(z_1)=c_1$. In other words, if we have a solution for $f(z)=c$, then if $c_1$ is not too far away from $c$ then we can find a solution $f(z_1)=c_1$, where $z_1$ is as close as we like to $z$. If $z$ is a single root of $f-c$, then this proof is as easy as considering the inverse, which must be continuous. If $z$ is a multiple root, it's more difficult but I think still doable.

Assuming that my continuity argument is correct, we can say that there are well-defined paths, i.e. there are no jumps. We need to take care with multiple roots, making sure they don't stray onto each other's paths, but I think it's doable.

But each root has a continuous path, and there has to be some sort of parametrization that, with a little care, we can show is periodic. Defining $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ as $g(x,y)=f(x+yi)$, we can then use the continuity and (real) differentiability of the gradient of $g$ combined with information on how $e^{i\theta}$ changes to show that there's a smooth path.

Do I have anything here, or is it all a load of nonsense? Let me know! :)

Comment: While your epislon delta proof would probably work, I suspect continuity follows more directly from the fact that the roots of a polynomial vary smoothly as you change the coefficients (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Continuous_dependence_on_coefficients).  As $\theta$ changes it basically changes the constant term of $f(z)$, so continuous changes to $\theta$ should produce continuous changes in the roots of $f(z)$.